# Failed to resolve: transition-1.2.0 error in building gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I want to build my application `Gradle` and I get the below error. I searched a lot but I couldn't find an error like this for `transition` and I don't know, what is `transition`!

> Failed to resolve: transition-1.2.0
> Affected Modules: app

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thanks. Your answer was correct and my problem solved. Please write your answer in a post that I can accept this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`Transition`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/transition/package-summary) API allows you to animate various kinds of layout changes automatically. You should try with

```
implementation "androidx.transition:transition:1.3.1" 
implementation "androidx.transition:transition-ktx:1.4.0-beta01"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is bug of Android Studio.

For fix it open `Menu - File - Project Structure`. In dialog box select `Project` and set Gradle version 6.0 or high, press `Ok` button and "`Sync project with Gradle files`".